# Pre-selecting options in Angular ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular, npm

I'm using the ng-multiselect-dropdown in Angular to create a multi-select drop-down as a custom header.  What I cannot seem to figure out is if there is a way to set which values I would pre-selected in the list.  Here is now my drop-down is coded:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="column.dropdown" let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" 
             ngx-datatable-header-template>
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="column.name"
             class="d-inline-block" [data]="this[column.prop]"
             [settings]="dropdownSettings">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</ng-template>
```

Is there a property I can set that will pre-select certain values in the list?  I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide us a plunker, jsfiddle or something like that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I should have read the API documentation more carefully.  It actually specifies how to do this by setting the [(ngModel)] attribute on the ng-multiselect-dropdown tag.

Comment: so weird. this is working only if there is nothing wrapping the push statement...

Answer (score 6):

Here, the ng-multiselect-dropdown pre-selection option value binds with ngModel and also I have shown the validation for ng-multiselect-dropdown:

```html
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
    formControlName="location"
    id="location"
    [data]="supplierList"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedSupplier"
    [settings]="supplierDropDownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onLocationSelect($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
<div *ngIf="submitted && formGroup.controls['location'].invalid"
    class="text-danger mt-1">
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['location'].errors.required">
                            This filed is required
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
public selectedSupplier: Array<SupplierModal> = [];
public warehouse: SupplierModal = { "id": 1, "name" : Company }
this.selectedSupplier = new Array<SupplierModal>();
this.selectedSupplier.push(this.warehouse);
```

Comment: this.myForm = this.fb.group({
                city: [this.selectedItems]
 });

Setting the selected item through formGroup fixed the issue for me.  
Follow exact steps in https://nileshpatel17.github.io/ng-multiselect-dropdown/

Answer (score 2):

Component HTML (With FormControl)

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
 [placeholder]="'Select Controller'"
 [data]="controllerList"
 formControlName="controller"
 [settings]="dropdownSettings"
 (onSelect)="onItemSelectController($event)"
 (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllController($event)" 
 (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelectController($event)"  
 (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAllController($event)" 
 (onDropDownClose)="onDropDownCloseController()">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Component TS (With FormControl)

```
controllerList: any;
addRoleForm: FormGroup;

dropdownSettings: any = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'item_id',
  textField: 'item_text',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};

this.addRoleForm = this.formBuilder.group({    
      controller: ['', Validators.compose(
        [Validators.required]
      )]          
});

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.selectedConcrollers = [
    {item_id: 1, item_text: 'value'},
    {item_id: 1, item_text: 'value'}
  ];

  this.addRoleForm.patchValue({
    controller: this.selectedConcrollers 
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution because using `[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"` within reactive form will be prohibited in future Angular (check warning in the console when doing that).

Answer (score 2):

.push() didn't work for me, seems like component is not reacting to push event.. I had to replace whole array in order to make it work.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selected" ...></ng-multiselect-dropdown>

this.selected = [{item_id: 1, item_name: 'xxxxx'}, {item_id: 2, item_name: 'yyyyyy'}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selected" ...></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

In typescript:

```
this.selected.push({item_id: 1, item_name: 'xxxxx'});
```

Answer (score 1):

ts file:

```
dropdownList = [];
selectedItems = [];
dropdownSettings = {};
this.dropdownList = [
    { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
    { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Bangaluru' },
    { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
    { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' },
    { item_id: 5, item_text: 'New Delhi' }
];
this.selectedItems = [
    { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
    { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' }
];
```

html file:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
  [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: It makes no sense to have to provide the `item_text` for the selected items, the component already has them in `dropDownList`. I only keep ids in the backend, not the names. This is not a very good component.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use ngModel inside the formGroup if its a standalone property or else it will give error